# How to extract URLs from FormLoginConfigurer?

Tags: java, spring-security

I want to gain access to the URLs set by the FormLoginConfigurer, in particular I want to extraxt the URL Strings for loginPage, loginProcessingUrl and failureUrl. These values are configured as follows:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .mvcMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .mvcMatchers("/**").authenticated())

                .formLogin(login -> login
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                        .failureUrl("/login?error")
                        .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                        .permitAll())

                .build();
    }
}
```

Within a CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler, concrete inside the determineTargetUrl method, I now want to make some decisions based on these URLs. The SuccessHandler looks like this:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException {

        handleRedirect(request, response, authentication);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

    private void handleRedirect(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException {

        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request, authentication);
        if (response.isCommitted()) return;
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    private String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, Authentication authentication) {
        Set<String> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        
        SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest) request.getSession()
                .getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");

        if (authorities.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) return "/admin";
        if (authorities.contains("ROLE_USER")) return savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();

        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    private void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) return;
        session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```

How can I extract the values for loginPage, loginProcessingUrl and failureUrl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define those URLs somewhere that you can use as a reference in both places. It could be in your `application.yml` file:

```yaml
security:
  form:
    login-url: "/login"
    login-success-url: "/success"
    other-property: 123
```

And in your code you inject them (note that the class has to be a bean):

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Value("security.form.login-url")
  private String loginUrl;

  @Value("security.form.login-success-url")
  private String loginSuccessUrl;
  // ...

}
```

You can also create a `ConfigurationProperties` to improve the code https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: So there is no easy way to get these values? Thank you, you've helped me a lot, because knowing your way is best practice I don't need to look any further and can sleep calmly again :)

Comment: Not really, if you want to override them then you are in responsible to provide them where needed